# Write to /res/drawable/ on the fly?

Tags: android

My widget reads an image from `/res/drawable/`.

I would like to be able to change the image and write it back out to the `/res/drawable/` structure.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Everything in the apk will be read only.
And it's even better: android doesn't extract the apk when you install a program, so the size consumed is kept to minimal.

Answer (score 9):

You cannot write to res/drawable.

Comment: Hello, is there official documention about this? thanks!

Answer (score 7):

Nope. But you can change your program to use alternate forms of storage.

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html