# How to download an image from URL and store it in drawable folder of my application dynamically?

Tags: android, imagedownload

In my project I want to download an image from a URL, and I want to share the image through Kik Messenger. The code for sharing the image in Kik Messenger is:

```
KikMessage message = new KikMessage("com.kik.myapp.id");
message.setImage(this, R.drawable.something);
```

So how can I store the image in the drawable folder?

Comment: A quick search pulled up these two: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3375166/android-drawable-images-from-url http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5469954/android-image-save-to-res-drawable-folder You should post your code, it will help with a solution.

Comment: your apk is read Only you can't save files on it!! save your image on your SDcard

Comment: @K_Anas I'd think internal storage would make more sense than external...

Answer (score 1):

Your application resource directory is read-only, so you simply can't do that.

Your best bet is to see if Kik Messenger offers any methods that take a Drawable rather than a resource ID.

**Update:** I just checked [the Kik Messenger docs](http://kik.com/dev/docs/android/index.html), and there are indeed two other methods that set the image: `setImage(BitmapDrawable)` and `setImage(File)`. The simplest option would probably be to save the image to internal storage and attach the file (and then delete it if you won't need it again).