# How to save a Drawable in the resource folder?

Tags: android, resources, drawable

I want to save this:

> private Drawable icon;
>   icon = pk.getApplicationIcon(procInfos.get(1).processName);

I get the icon then i want to save it in the resource folder.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's not possibile. See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5469954/android-image-save-to-res-drawable-folder

Answer (score 2):

Resources are read-only at runtime; you cannot "save" anything "in the resource folder". You are welcome to save data to internal or external storage.

In this case, I doubt you should even be doing that, as those icons are meant to be read on the fly from `PackageManager`, not stored. After all, not only will those icons change as apps get updated, but you do not have rights to those icons.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to save a static file in your application at compile time, save the file in your project `res/raw/` directory. You can open it with `openRawResource()`, passing the `R.raw.<filename> resource ID`. This method returns an `InputStrea`m that you can use to read the file (but you cannot write to the original file). You Can save images dynamically in `sqlite` database [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20200718180158/http://www.tutorialforandroid.com/2009/10/how-to-insert-image-data-to-sqlite.html) is a tutorial on it. `You can't save the image at Runtime in application folders.`