# URL image to imageview to drawable

Tags: android, url

```
ImageView img1;
    img1 = (ImageView) findViewById (R.id.img1);

        URL newurl = new URL("http://10.0.2.2:80/Gallardo/Practice/files/images/donut.jpg");
        Bitmap mIcon_val = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(newurl.openConnection() .getInputStream());
        img1.setImageBitmap(mIcon_val);
```

I get image from url but I want to store it to my drawable, how?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5469954/android-image-save-to-res-drawable-folder

Comment: i dont think thats a good idea.. why cant you save to sdcard

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everything in the apk will be read only.
So you can't write to drawable.

you have to use "blob" to store image.

ex: to store a image in to db

```
public void insertImg(int id , Bitmap img ) {   


    byte[] data = getBitmapAsByteArray(img); // this is a function

    insertStatement_logo.bindLong(1, id);       
    insertStatement_logo.bindBlob(2, data);

    insertStatement_logo.executeInsert();
    insertStatement_logo.clearBindings() ;

}

 public static byte[] getBitmapAsByteArray(Bitmap bitmap) {
    ByteArrayOutputStream outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    bitmap.compress(CompressFormat.PNG, 0, outputStream);       
    return outputStream.toByteArray();
}
```

to retrieve a image from db

```
public Bitmap getImage(int i){

    String qu = "select img  from table where feedid=" + i ;
    Cursor cur = db.rawQuery(qu, null);

    if (cur.moveToFirst()){
        byte[] imgByte = cur.getBlob(0);
        cur.close();
        return BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(imgByte, 0, imgByte.length);
    }
    if (cur != null && !cur.isClosed()) {
        cur.close();
    }       

    return null ;
}
```

You can also check this [saving image to database](http://www.androidhub4you.com/2012/09/hello-friends-today-i-am-going-to-share.html)

Comment: Sir may I ask what is this line? insertStatement_logo.bindLong(1, id);       
    insertStatement_logo.bindBlob(2, data);

    insertStatement_logo.executeInsert();
    insertStatement_logo.clearBindings() ;

Answer (score 1):

You can construct Drawable by using this [constructor](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/BitmapDrawable.html#BitmapDrawable(android.content.res.Resources,%20android.graphics.Bitmap)):

```
Drawable drawable = new BitmapDrawable(getResources(), mIcon_val);
```

You can set it to the ImageView like so:

```
img1.setImageDrawable(drawable);
```

Answer (score 0):

Its not possible to place image in drawable folder while running the apk.. Saving an image to SDcard is possible..

Comment: How about database? SQLite?

Comment: yes possible try http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9357668/how-to-store-image-in-sqlite-database , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19538966/how-to-store-an-image-in-the-database-android ,  http://www.coderzheaven.com/2012/12/23/store-image-android-sqlite-retrieve-it/