# How to save the image that clicked from camera application to drawable folder and how to share it in android?

Tags: android, image, file-upload

Hi i am using a camera application in android. In my application, I want to save the photo that clicked to device's internal storage(in res folder) and also want to share it. I tried the code as shown bellow.

```
Camera.PictureCallback jpegCallback = new PictureCallback() 
    {
        public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera) 
        {
            FileOutputStream outStream = null;
            try 
            {               
                outStream = new FileOutputStream(String.format("/sdcard/%d.jpg", System.currentTimeMillis()));  
                outStream.write(data);
                outStream.close();
                sendBroadcast(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_MOUNTED, Uri.parse("file://"+ Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory())));
                Log.d(TAG, "on pictureTaken" + data.length);
            } 
            catch (FileNotFoundException e) 
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } 
            catch (IOException e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } 
            finally
            {}
            setContentView(R.layout.main2);         
            BitmapFactory.Options opts = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(data, 0, data.length,opts);
            imgView = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.photoResultView);
            imgView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);    
            upload = (Button) findViewById(R.id.upload);
            upload.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() 
            {
                public void onClick(View v) 
                {
                    Intent sharingIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                    Uri screenshotUri = Uri.parse("/sdcard/%d.jpg");

                    sharingIntent.setType("image/jpg");
                    sharingIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, screenshotUri);
                    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sharingIntent, "Share image using"));
                }
            });
        }
    };
```

if anyone knows about it help me..

Answer (score 0):

You can't store images or picture taken from Camera to drawable folder, you can store them to SDCard rather.
You can check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3374061/write-to-res-drawable-on-the-fly) link.

**UPDATE**

You can save the Image taken using this,

```
File myFile = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+File.separator+"my_image.jpg");
                try {
                    myFile.createNewFile();
                    FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(myFile);
                    outputStream.write(data);
                }
                catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
```

Comment: Hi Lalit Poptani, im trying to save the image to sdcard and share it as shown above. But i can't save it. Therefor I need to save it in internal storage and share from there. Could u help me, if u know about it..

Comment: I had added the stuff to save image to sdcard, you can check it.