# How to write a file in Android to the raw folder?

Tags: java, android

I think this is a pretty basic question.

I am currently writing a file like this:

```
File output = new File("exampleout.mid");
```

Now, I want to write the file to ../myproject/res/raw

I read I could do it by putting the complete url in the "". BUT. Since this is an Android app. What is the full url? I don;t have to write /home/.../myproject/...?

Is the solution:

```
File output = new File("/res/raw/exampleout.mid");
```

Or do I need a higher url structure?

Sorry about asking this simple question, but since I use an Android emulator, I cannot check if the file is actually in the right place.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You cannot write a file to raw folder. Its read-only. Precisely you can't modify anything contained within "Res" folder on the fly.

Check this out, https://stackoverflow.com/a/3374149

Comment: Ok thanks! The thing is that I want to playback this file with MediaPlayer and MediaPlayer want the files to be in /res/raw. Any idea on how to solve this?

Comment: But you can use MediaPlayer to play sound from any directory rite?

Comment: I didn't know that. Let me examine further. Is there a directory you can recommend for that and how would I write to that?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use iText on Android or the Google App Engine, you need to use iTextG.

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.itextpdf:itextg:5.5.10'
}
```

Source: [iText Official Site](https://developers.itextpdf.com/itextg-android)