# Error in adding text to existing txt file

Tags: android

Firstly, i know there are same questions in this web site but i couldn't add text to my existing txt file. maybe i miss out something but where ? anyway here are my codes.

i have translate.txt file. it is /raw folder.and When i click the button, the words which are written in the `editTexts(w1,w2)` must be added to the existing translate.txt file.But it is not working..

```
public class Add extends Activity {

EditText w1,w2;
Button save;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.add);

    w1=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.idText1);
    w2=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.idText2);
    save=(Button) findViewById(R.id.idSave);

    save.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            String word1=w1.getText().toString();
            String word2=w2.getText().toString();
            writefile(word1,word2);


        }

    });



}

public void writefile(String word1,String word2)

{
    try
    {
        String finalstring=new String(word1 + " " + word2);
        FileOutputStream fOut = openFileOutput("translate.txt",MODE_APPEND);
        OutputStreamWriter osw = new OutputStreamWriter(fOut);
        osw.write(finalstring);
        osw.flush();
        osw.close();
        Toast.makeText(this, "Saved", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } catch(Exception e)
        {
        Toast.makeText(this, "ERROR!!!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

}

}
```

Comment: what do you mean you can't? You don't know how to or your code isn't working?

Comment: i mean the code isn't working and i don't know how to fix it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A) Code to write APPEND file in Android

```
public void writefile(String word1,String word2)
        try {
                    String path = sdCard.getAbsolutePath() + "/";

        File logFile = new File(path + "translate.txt");
        if (!logFile.exists()) {
            logFile.createNewFile();
        }

        // BufferedWriter for performance, true to set append to file

        FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(logFile, true);
        BufferedWriter buf = new BufferedWriter(fw);


            buf.append(word1 + " " + word2);
            buf.newLine();
            buf.flush();

        }
        buf.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

B) Rule/ Permission 
**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

**EDIT** For user

You cannot write a file to raw folder. Its read-only. Precisely you can't modify anything contained within "Res" folder on the fly.

Check this out, https://stackoverflow.com/a/3374149

Comment: txt file is in the /raw folder. in your code is related the sdCard ?

Comment: i'm new the coding android so i just created the file in the raw folder

Comment: By this code, it automatically create a file in your InternalStorage if not found. And keep (Appending to it). So you don't need to create it manually. RAW folder cannot be appended or anything cannot be created in it. from the APP

Answer (score 1):

Just in case you don't want to store the data in sd card and want to use the previous method
the way you was creating a file and stroing data to it was not actually editing the file in res/ raw folder ( because it can not be edited )

but the data you was writing was actually stored in a private file associated with this Context's application package for reading.

hence it was there and the file can be read as follow:

```
    private void readFile() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    try {
        FileInputStream fin = openFileInput("translate.txt");
        InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(fin);
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);
                    String str;
                    StringBuilder str2 = new StringBuilder();
        while ((str = br.readLine()) != null) {
            str2 = str2.append(str);
        }
        isr.close();
        editText.setText(str2.toString());
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

you can follow this method incase you dont want to store file in sd card because files in sd crad can be read by anyone.