# How to save the bitmap image into the Drawable folder in Android

Tags: android, android-image, android-drawable, android-gallery

In my app I save the images into the gallery, but I want to save the images into the `drawable` folder directly its possible.

Comment: NO,drawable folder is present in the packaged apk. It is read only. So you cannot save images to it.

Comment: K fine there is any alternative solutions.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot modify resources -- including adding or removing them -- at runtime. You are welcome to store images at runtime in internal or external storage.

Comment: It is possible to save the images into drawable.

Comment: No @Manoj. It is not possible to save images to drawable directory at run-time. Please take a look at this thread - [Write to /res/drawable/ on the fly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3374061/write-to-res-drawable-on-the-fly)