# Saving to drawable folder programmatically in Android

Tags: android, drawable

I'm looking to have a user select an image from the gallery, and have this file saved as a permanent drawable resource when they open the app at a later time.  Is this possible?

I mean as an object in the actual drawable folder.

Comment: After A Long Search , I found it's not allowed to do that. Check this Answer from more [info](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3374149/3474171)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Write to /res/drawable/ on the fly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3374061/write-to-res-drawable-on-the-fly)

Comment: Hello, is there official documention about this? thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No, it's not possible. "The drawable folder" doesn't exist as a file system folder at runtime - it's part of your (read-only) binary .apk file.

Comment: Hello, is there official documention about this? thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You could instead save the image at internal folder and/or define a preference string.
Check this old answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/3374138/4618976