# Download a song from uri and store it in app specific folder

Tags: android

I am trying to download a song from a server using URI and want to store it in res/raw folder. How can i do that in android studio.

Comment: Please provide some code, of whatever you've tried.

Answer (score 0):

You cant store mp3 or any file in res/raw folder , it is only read only when apk made [read this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3374061/write-to-res-drawable-on-the-fly/3374149#3374149),
you can store file in your phone storage.

code :

```
      try{

      File newFile = newFile(android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),"Your Folder Name");
      if(!newFile.exists())
      newFile.mkdirs();

      File f=new File(newFile,songname+".mp3");
      URL url = new URL(yourSongUrl); 

        InputStream input = new BufferedInputStream(url.openStream());
        OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream(f);

        byte data[] = new byte[1024];
        long total = 0;
        int count=0;
        while ((count = input.read(data)) != -1) {
            total++;
            Log.e("while","A"+total);

            output.write(data, 0, count);
        }

        output.flush();
        output.close();
        input.close();
     }
     Catch(Exception e){e.printStackTrace();}
```