# Get link from Glide to use it as a resource later

Tags: android, android-glide

Now i downloaded .svg file from asset.
Can I use Glide to get a link to a resource(namely, I have a link from the server that I want to display as an icon)

**UPD:**

I tried next functional from this [library](http://bigbadaboom.github.io/androidsvg/SVGImageView.html):

```
val uri = Uri.parse("https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/3/35/Tux.svg")
bankLogoView.setImageURI(uri)
```

And get next error:

> E/SVGImageView: File not found: https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/3/35/Tux.svg

Comment: you want to get link to a resource by its name using glide?

Comment: It isn't possible. Read this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3374061/write-to-res-drawable-on-the-fly

Comment: @MaxAves smth like this i hope so

Comment: @Morozov Nope, this is not about the glide. You have to get the full path from your server or know the structure of it, so you can build it yourself